# Android : Google Sign-in Invalid token

Tags: android, token, google-signin

I am getting an error from the token I am receiving through google sign in android:

> { "error": "invalid_token", "error_description": "Invalid Value" }

I also noticed that my token looks a bit short compared to the one I am getting in iOS:

```
ya29.4AFYx2XNZ1sdfdzhWo-of-fSpsDPjgmATx-J82mCjqZJXglwj8VOvedpY_YXJgEVIWe
```

I am getting the token like this:

```
 private class RetrieveTokenTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String accountName = params[0];
            String scopes = "oauth2:profile email";
            String token = null;
            try {
                token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), accountName, scopes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
                //startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQ_SIGN_IN_REQUIRED);
            } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
            return token;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String token) {
            super.onPostExecute(token);
            Log.i("Token Value: ", token);
        }
}
```

Any idea what might be happening, or how to debug more in depth the problem?

Comment: Are you sending the same scope on iOS?

Comment: How are you getting the authorisation from the user in your case? The way we do it, is that we're prompting the user for the permissions at first and then we fetch the `AccessToken` the same way as you're doing it, except I'm using `Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName()` that takes a `GoogleApiClient` object. See this: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in

Comment: I'm not sure how I am getting the autorization exactly, I am clicking on google + button and it automatically authorize it, I get my username, my email, and this token... Do you have an example code of the way you do it?

Comment: Did you get seccess on your way? I am exactly intrested in, did you get refresh token and expiry time? If yes, say me please which way because i have spend quite a few time to get it((

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok so I found the answer, the scopes must be written like this:

```
String scopes = "oauth2:"
                + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN
                + " "
                + Scopes.PROFILE;
```

And the endpoint differs from android to iOS

```
'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?id_token='; //for iOS
'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token='; //for android
```