# Google Sign-In for Android Invalid ID Token

Tags: android, googlesigninaccount, google-signin

I am following the instructions on the Google Sign-In for Android guide (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth), and I am trying to validate my ID token. When I go to 
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=XYZ123 in my browser
(where XYZ123 is my id token I retrieved using 
`String idToken = acct.getIdToken();`, I get this response:

```
{
 "error_description": "Invalid Value"
}
```

My id token starts with eyJ and is 1038 characters long.

I've also tried the solution here [Android : Google Sign-in Invalid token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32329229/android-google-sign-in-invalid-token) to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out my token just expired. I grabbed a new token and it works!

Comment: How did you get a new token? every time i request a token via getIdToken() I get the same old expired token. Any pointers/help is highly appreciated

Comment: @rakeshkashyap, that's odd. In my onCreate method, I use:    `GoogleSignInOptions gso = new  GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id)).requestEmail().build();` I believe if the token has expired, that method should just retrieve a new one. I just run my program on the Android AVD, sign in on the AVD, then grab the token using `getIdToken()` in the debugger.
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInOptions.Builder.html#public-methods

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37363213/google-always-returns-expired-id-tokenjwt here is my SO on the same. I will be very happy if you can answer

Comment: This answer was actually helpful. Oops. 

Comment: If you try to print the idToken to the console in Android, it will truncate the string to 1024 characters. And idToken may be longer than that.

Answer (score 1):

If the idToken that you are passing to the function is from the log of your mobile app, it is likely that you are not getting the entire idToken printed in the log due to the limitations of generic log.

I used the below code snippet to print out the idToken and used that in the API which gave me a success response.

```dart
print('ID TOKEN');
String token = googleAuth.idToken;
while (token.length > 0) {
    int initLength = (token.length >= 500 ? 500 : token.length);
    print(token.substring(0, initLength));
    int endLength = token.length;
    token = token.substring(initLength, endLength);
}
```

Note: Although this snippet is flutter-specific, you can reuse the logic in any framework.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.
For me clearing app data completely solved the issue. Seemed like an old expired token got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

From my own answer in another question:

In my case, I was testing this in Unity and I copied the `idToken` value that I printed in logcat. Turns out, there is some character or size limit (1024 bytes?) for a line in either adb logcat or Unity's `Debug.Log()` method. So the printed token value was getting truncated. What I did then for testing was that I copied the token value to clipboard during runtime and then checked again with the tokeninfo endpoint `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=` and it was accepted.